# JQuery Cycle Plugin and CSS Sprite - no hover registered with Opera

Tags: jquery, css, opera, z-index

Using JQuery Cycle plugin to create a rotating background. Also using Blueprint for CSS

The images are within an absolutely positioned DIV z-index:1. Another absolutely positioned DIV is placed right on top of this one with z-index:999.

Within the top DIV is a CSS Sprite Menu.

The sprite menu works with every browser I've tested, FF3.6, IE8/7/6, Chrome, Safari.. but not in Opera 10.6

The menu shows clearly and is not being blocked by the rotating background images, but no hover is being picked up. Also, when I use "inspect element" and hover, it functions correctly, once I disable "Find Element by Clicking" it goes back to not registering.

I think it may have something to do with z-index since it looks like Jquery Cycle plugin is changing the z-indexes of the images, but it only goes up to z-index:6... so I'm lost.

[Link to the site](http://www.flirtygirlfitness.com/index2.html)

**The gist of the CSS**

```
#background-images {
   width:950px;
   height:515px;
   position:absolute;
   top:0; left:0;
   z-index:1;
   }

#absolute-overlay {
   position:absolute;
   top:0; left:0;
   z-index:998;
   }

#relative-overlay {
   position:relative;
   width:950px;
   height:515px;
   }

#navbar {
   width:410px;
   height:279px;
   background:url(../images/savvier/menu-sprite.png);
   padding:0;
   position:relative;
   float:right;
   clear:both;
   }
```

**The gist of the HTML**

```
<div id="background-images">
<div class="slideshow">
<img src="images/savvier/rotate/rotate_1.jpg" width="950" height="515" />
<img src="images/savvier/rotate/rotate_2.jpg" width="950" height="515" style="display:none;" />
<img src="images/savvier/rotate/rotate_3.jpg" width="950" height="515" style="display:none;" />
<img src="images/savvier/rotate/rotate_4.jpg" width="950" height="515" style="display:none;" />
<img src="images/savvier/rotate/rotate_5.jpg" width="950" height="515" style="display:none;" />
<img src="images/savvier/rotate/rotate_6.jpg" width="950" height="515" style="display:none;" />
</div>
</div>

<div class="span-24" id="absolute-overlay"><div id="relative-overlay">
<div class="logo"><img src="images/savvier/logo.png" alt="Flirty Girl Fitness&trade;" /></div>
<ul id="navbar">
<li id="menu-chicago"><a href="http://chicago.flirtygirlfitness.com/chicago_html/"></a></li>
    <li id="menu-toronto"><a href="http://toronto.flirtygirlfitness.com/toronto_html/"></a></li>
    <li id="menu-activewear"><a href="http://www.flirtygirlactivewear.com/"></a></li>
    <li id="menu-instructor"><a href="http://www.flirtification.com/"></a></li>
    <li id="menu-findclass"><a href="http://www.flirtification.com/find-class.asp"></a></li>
    <li id="menu-tv"><a href="http://flirtygirlfit.com/"></a></li>
</ul>
</div></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, this is a way to do it that I've never seen before - you create completely empty A tags and position them carefully on top of an otherwise unrelated image, to make the illusion that you have clickable "buttons".

First I'll explain why Opera doesn't handle it, give you a quick workaround - and then say a few words about why you might want to consider doing things differently..

Opera doesn't detect any mouse actions because it tries to ignore mouse actions above empty elements under some circumstances (in case the user actually tries to click something "behind" those empty elements). Here we are trying to copy what IE does - apparently not exact enough, since IE works and Opera fails even when I remove your conditional comments and IE-specific stylesheet.

The quick (and hacky) workaround is to make sure something makes Opera think mouse actions directed at the empty A elements are significant. For example, this should be a harmless way to deal with it:

```
<script>if(document.addEventListener)document.addEventListener('mouseover', function(){}, true)</script>
```

This adds one simple capturing mouseover listener that will fire on hovering anything, including the invisible empty links. Except for using a tiny bit of extra CPU it will do absolutely nothing, but Opera will notice that something is trying to observe the mouse interaction and the elements will become interactive.

Now, the code you have deployed is in my opinion not the best way to do it. The reason is that it is not as accessible as other ways to do the same thing - neither to assistive technology nor to browsers that reformat the page due to small screens or user preferences. Your links have absolutely no information except the URL - no link text, nothing. Because they relate to one single image you can not give each button a separate alternative text either.

My suggestion would be using an image map (HTML's MAP element) instead, with appropriate ALT="" and/or TITLE="" attributes on the areas. This is a way to do it that both assistive technologies and browsers that need to modify your page's intended layout should understand.

Comment: The way that the links are laid out is called a CSS Sprite Menu: http://www.alistapart.com/articles/sprites

I've used them extensively over the last 3 years without any negative effects. However, this is the first time I have tried laying them over another div while changing z-index the way the jQuery cycle plugin does.

Anyways, thanks for the help, I will look more into your response tomorrow when I get to work

Comment: Interesting that this was recommended on ALA - I will have a look at that article and the discussion to see if anyone discussed the accessibility drawbacks I think this method has.

Comment: The article does not explicitly discuss this but it has this parenthetical note:

(We’ll ignore any text inside the links for the time being. Apply your favorite image replacement technique later to hide the text you’ll end up adding.)

Comment: I gave up trying to get it to work in every browser. I removed the rotating images DIV with CSS and then added javascript to detect the Opera browser and if not Opera then show the rotating images. It's a bit of a hack but...